# Sqlalchemy; count items between two dates over a time period

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

My postgres DB has a Price table where I store price data for a bunch of products. For each Price object I store when it was created (Price.timestamp), and whenever there is a new price for the product, I create a new Price object, and for the old Price object I store when it ended (Price.end_time). Both times are datetime objects.

Now, I want to count how many Prices there are at over a time period. Easy I thought, so I did the query below:

```
trunc_date = db.func.date_trunc('day', Price.timestamp)

query = db.session.query(trunc_date, db.func.count(Price.id))
query = query.order_by(trunc_date.desc())
query = query.group_by(trunc_date)
prices_count = query.all()
```

Which is great, but only counts how many prices were new/created for each day. So what I thought I could do, was to filter so that I would get prices where the trunc_date is between the beginning and the end for the Price, like below:

```
query = query.filter(Price.timestamp < trunc_date < Price.time_ended)
```

But apparently you are not allowed to use trunc_date this way. Can anyone help me with how I am supposed to write my query?

Data example:

```
Price.id    Price.timestamp    Price.time_ended
1           2022-18-09         2022-26-09
2           2022-13-09         2022-20-09
```

The query result i would like to get is:

```
2022-27-09; 0
2022-26-09; 1
2022-25-09; 1
...
2022-20-09; 2
2022-19-09; 2
2022-18-09; 2
2022-17-09; 1
...
2022-12-09; 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

First I created a date range by using a subquery.

```
todays_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 1)
numdays = 360
min_date = todays_date - timedelta(days = numdays)

date_series = db.func.generate_series(min_date , todays_date, timedelta(days=1))
trunc_date = db.func.date_trunc('days', date_series)
subquery = db.session.query(trunc_date.label('day')).subquery()
```

Then I used the subquery as input in my original query, and I was finally able to filter on the dates from the subquery.

```
query = db.session.query(subquery.c.day, db.func.count(Price.id))
query = query.order_by(subquery.c.day.desc())
query = query.group_by(subquery.c.day)
query = query.filter(Price.timestamp < subquery.c.day)
query = query.filter(Price.time_ended > subquery.c.day)
```

Now, query.all() will give you a nice list that counts the prices for each day specified in the date_series.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried separating the conditions inside the filter?

```
query = db.session.\
    query(trunc_date, db.func.count(Price.id)).\
    filter(
        (Price.timestamp < trunc_date),
        (trunc_date < Price.time_ended)
        ).\
    group_by(trunc_date).\
    order_by(trunc_date.desc()).\
    all()
```

Comment: Yes, I have but it returns 0 items. Not sure if the trunc_date is meant to be used in filters at all.

Comment: If you do `print(db.session.query(...))` without the final `all()` you can see the SQL statement that gets generated. You can then play around with the `WHERE` conditions to see why you're not returning any results.

Comment: I cant seem to find anything to point my finger at:                        
SELECT date_trunc(%(date_trunc_2)s, price.timestamp) AS date_trunc_1, count(price.id) AS count_1

WHERE date_trunc(%(date_trunc_2)s, price.timestamp) BETWEEN price.timestamp AND price.time_ended GROUP BY date_trunc(%(date_trunc_2)s, price.timestamp)

Comment: Haha, of course. You're creating a trunc date from Price.timestamp. Which means `Price.timestamp < trunc_date` will always be `False` (the truncated date will always be smaller than the timestamp it was generated from). Just swap your logic around.

Comment: Aha, but I still dont get how I can swap the logic around, could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: `(Price.timestamp > trunc_date)`- but on reflection I'm not sure this is getting you to what your trying to achieve. As in I'm not sure you've got the SQL logic correct. May be worth asking another question and demonstrating the result your trying to get with some data.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. Thanks anyways. I'll try to post a new question with better explanation of the results I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
trunc_date.between(Price.timestamp, Price.time_ended)
```

Comment: I tried swapping in query.filter(trunc_date.between(Price.timestamp, Price.time_ended)) but it still gives me zero results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).